# Check unique value when define concrete class for abstract variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, design-patterns

Suppose that I have this architecture for my classes:

```
# abstracts.py
import abc
class AbstractReader(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
  
    @classmethod
    def get_reader_name(cl):
        return cls._READER_NAME

    @classmethod
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def _READER_NAME(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError

# concretes.py
from .abstracts import AbstractReader
class ReaderConcreteNumber1(AbstractReader):
    _READER_NAME = "NAME1"

class ReaderConcreteNumber2(AbstractReader):
    _READER_NAME = "NAME2"
```

Also I have a manager classes that find concrete classes by `_READER_NAME` variable. So I need to define unique `_READER_NAME` for each of my concrete classes.

***how do I check that  `NAME1` and `NAME2` are unique when concrete classes are going to define?***

Comment: What if you define some concrete reader in some unused test module which happens to have a duplicated name, but never actually gets used? This is a weird constraint to try to enforce…

Comment: What do you need the `_READER_NAME` for? `instance.__class__.__name__` would give you the class name. Can you use this? 
Otherwise you really need some spooky meta-programming on the interpreter...

Comment: I have a manager classes that  find concrete classes by `_READER_NAME` variable. So I need to define unique for each of my concrete classes. hope I have made the whole thing clear @Cpt.Hook

Comment: You can create a singleton and "register" the class once it is discovered by the interpreter. The Singleton can than hold also the mapping from name to class.

Comment: Can you answer? @Cpt.Hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a metaclass with a constructor that uses a set to keep track of the name of each instantiating class and raises an exception if a given name already exists in the set:

```
class UniqueName(type):
    names = set()

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict):
        name = classdict['_READER_NAME']
        if name in metacls.names:
            raise ValueError(f"Class with name '{name}' already exists.")
        metacls.names.add(name)
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict)
```

And make it the metaclass of your `AbstractReader` class. since Python does not allow a class to have multiple metaclasses, you would need to make `AbstractReader` inherit from `abc.ABCMeta` instead of having it as a metaclass:

```
class AbstractReader(abc.ABCMeta, metaclass=UniqueName):
    ... # your original code here
```

Or if you want to use `ABCMeta` as metaclass in your `AbstractReader`, just override `ABCMeta` class and set child ABC as `metaclass` in `AbstractReader`:

```
class BaseABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta):
    """
    Check unique name for _READER_NAME variable
    """
    _readers_name = set()

    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        reader_name = namespace['_READER_NAME']
        if reader_name in mcls._readers_name:
            raise ValueError(f"Class with name '{reader_name}' already exists. ")
        mcls._readers_name.add(reader_name)

        return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)

class AbstractReader(metaclass=BaseABCMeta):
    # Your codes ...
```

So that:

```
class ReaderConcreteNumber1(AbstractReader):
    _READER_NAME = "NAME1"

class ReaderConcreteNumber2(AbstractReader):
    _READER_NAME = "NAME1"
```

would produce:

```
ValueError: Class with name 'NAME1' already exists.
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MerryEveryInternet

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you :) But I can't change my abstract meta class. Can you override you meta class so I use it as decorator or inherit from it?

Comment: Can you help me in this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645921/concurrency-for-run-tree-of-functions-that-use-return-of-each-other-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This is a very special case, but it can be solved with a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

To ease things for our selfes we first create a singleton annotation

```
# anotations.py

def singleton(clazz):
    """Singleton annotator ensures the annotated class is a singleton"""

    class ClassW(clazz):
        """Creates a new sealed class from the object to create."""
        _instance = None

        def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            if ClassW._instance is None:
                ClassW._instance = super(ClassW, cls).__new__(clazz, *args, **kwargs)
                ClassW._instance._sealed = False

            return ClassW._instance

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self._sealed:
                return

            super(ClassW, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._sealed = True

    ClassW.__name__ = clazz.__name__
    return ClassW
```

Now we construct a singleton  **Registry** class, to register our classes with and to do the checking.

```
# registry.py

from .annotations import singleton 

@singleton
class ReaderRegistry:
    """
    Singleton class to register processing readers

    ### Usage
    To register a block call the register function with an ID and the class object.
        ReaderRegistry().register('FooName', FooReader)
    The class for the block can then be obtained via
        Registry()['FooName']

    """
    registry = {}

    def register(self, key: str, clazz: Type[Block]) -> None:
        """Register a new reader. Names must be unique within the registry"""
        if key in self:
            raise f"Reader with key {key} already registered."
        self.registry[key] = clazz

    def __contains__(self, key: str) -> bool:
        return key in self.registry.keys()

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> Type[Block]:
        return self.registry[key]
```

Now, you can

```
#concretes.py 

from .abstracts import AbstractReader
from .registry import ReaderRegistry

class ReaderConcreteNumber1(AbstractReader):
    _READER_NAME = "NAME1"

# Note that this is OUTSIDE and AFTER the class definition, 
# e.g. end of the file. 
RederRegistry().register(ReaderConcreteNumber1._READER_NAME , ReaderConcreteNumber1)
```

If a reader with such a name exists in the registry already there will be an exception thrown once the file is imported. Now, you can just lookip the classes to construct by theire naume in the registry, e.g.

```
if reader _namenot in ReaderRegistry():
    raise f"Block [{reader _name}] is not known."

reader = ReaderRegistry()[reader _name]
```